# Sysinternal Close Handle working in Command Prompt But Not Powershell

Tags: powershell, sysinternals

I have a strange issue. I am trying to close down a handle using Powershell using this 1 liner:

```
(&"D:\handle.exe" -p "–c C –p 3348 -y")
```

I am getting the following response:

> No matching handles found.

When I run the exact same command in Command Prompt

```
handle.exe -c C -p 3348 -y
```

I get:

> Handle closed.

I am running Powershell and Command Prompt as Admin.

edit: Note: I can run the same command inside the Powershell Command Window and get the same expected result as I did from the normal Windows Command Prompt.

Comment: `-p` will resolve to the `-PipelineVariable` common parameter, remove it

Comment: I've tried (&"D:\TeamCity\Handle\handle.exe" "–c C –p 3348 -y") still the same

Comment: External (ie not built into PowerShell) commands generally don't need any special handling try using `&"D:\handle.exe" –c C –p 3348 -y`: I suspect `handle` is looking for a process name "–c C –p 3348 -y". And putting only the parameters into quotes will pass them as a single parameter when they'll need to be separate

Comment: Thanks Richard, tried that as well but its not passing in any arguments into the handle exe.

Comment: Note: I can run the same Command Prompt command inside the Powershell Command window and get the same expected result as I did from the normal Command Prompt.

Comment: I've just tried `&"C:\bin\handle.exe" -p exp` and it worked fine from a 64bit PSH 5.1 console

Comment: yes that works for me was well but &"D:\handle.exe" –c C –p 3348 -y does not. So what am I missing. 'No Arguments will dump all file references'

Comment: `&"C:\bin\handle.exe" -p 2376 -c C98` just worked (but did require an elevated PSH)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165651/discussion-between-dritzz-and-richard).

Comment: I did get the "No arguments will dump all file references." error when trying to close a handle but specifying a process by name (to close handles you need the process id).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need any fancy syntax. PowerShell can run command-line programs just like `cmd.exe` can. Just type the command you want and press `Enter`.

```
handle -c C -p 3348 -y
```

It is likely you need to run this from an elevated PowerShell window, but that's not different from `cmd.exe`.